# @Autowire MockMvc - Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-test-mvc

Given the Repository

```java
public interface ResourceRepository extends CrudRepository<Resource, Long> { ... }
```

The following test code:

```java
@WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class RestResourceTests {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void create_ValidResource_Should201() {
    String requestJson = "...";

    mockMvc.perform(
      post("/resource")
        .content(requestJson)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      .andExpect(status().isCreated()); // This fails with 404
  }

}
```

In order to fix the issue, I need to inject the `WebApplicationContext` and manually create the `MockMvc` object as follows:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class RestResourceTests {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: what error happens with the first impl?

Comment: That's how I've always done it.  Usually I have one abstract class to setup the MockMvc instance since I also apply some security filters, and restdoc configurations.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe it 404's I put a comment in the expect.

Comment: can you set debug logging for spring web and/or post the controller too? Should be no real difference between the two.

Comment: Pure `@RestController` or `@Controller` instances work just fine, it's when you involve resources exposed through Spring Data Rest.

Comment: Can you post the controller?

Comment: There is no controller per se, I added an example Spring Data Repository

Comment: I can't understand the problem.

Comment: Basically, if you use a `RestRepository`, you can't use `@WebMvcTest` to auto inject `MockMvc`, you need to inject `WebApplicationContext` and create the `MockMvc` manually.  Given this is Spring Boot, it should 'just work'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out a "clean" solution, but it feels like a bug to me.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc // <-- this is the fix 
public class RestResourceTests {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc; // <-- now injects with repositories wired.
```

The reason I feel like this is a bug, the `@WebMvcTest` annotation already places the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` annotation on the class under test.

It feels like `@WebMvcTest` isn't looking at the web components loaded with `@RestRepository`.

Comment: The documentation is very specific with that.