# mockMvc beans is always null in my integration tests in springboot 3.2.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito

my mocked repositories beans are always null in my integration tests in springboot 3.2.2
What I don't understand why I'm obliged to mock all dependent beans. Is there anyway to do it automatically ?
Sometimes mockMvc is null too.

I have tried to remove

```java
@WebMvcTest(DeliveryController.class)
```

and use the following :

```java
@RunAs("SpringRunner.class")
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

But in vain. mockMvc is always null.

I don't want to add the following initialization code since mockMvc shouldn't be null

```java
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new DeliveryController(new DeliveryServiceImpl())).build();
}
```

```java
@WebMvcTest(DeliveryController.class)
public class DeliveryControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private static MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private DeliveryRepository deliveryRepository; // Mocking the repository

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository; // Mocking the repository

    @Test
    public void testCreateDelivery() throws Exception {
        DeliveryEntity delivery = DeliveryEntity.builder().deliveryId(1L).description("Test package").build();

        Mockito.when(deliveryRepository.save(Mockito.any(DeliveryEntity.class))).thenReturn(delivery);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/deliveries/1").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{\"description\": \"Test package\"}")) // Use a JSON payload that matches your Delivery object structure
                .andExpect(status().isOk());// .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        Mockito.verify(deliveryRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(Mockito.any(DeliveryEntity.class));
    }

    // Add more test methods for other endpoints
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

mockMvc shouldn't be null and repositories beans should not be null too.

Here are my dependencies in the pom file

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId> 
            <scope>runtime</scope> <optional>true</optional> </!dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
``
```

Comment: try with @AutoConfigureMockMvc on top of DeliveryControllerTest.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589893/autowire-mockmvc-spring-data-rest

Comment: @pochopsp WebMvcTest is referencing already AutoConfigureMockMvc so adding it is useless

Comment: that's what the answer I linked you said too... They say it's a bug, try to read the whole answer in the link, maybe it could help you

Comment: Which `@Test` are you using, pleaes provide the used imports for the whole test. In your dependencies remove the `org.slf4j` one and the `org.junit.jupiter` one. Those are already included by others. I also wonder why you added `hibernate-core` as that is provided through `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. If you want to override the version use `hibernate.version` in the `properties` block of your pom to override the version.

Comment: Also `MockMvc` shouldn't be `static`, you cannot use `@Autowired` on static fields.

Comment: @M.Deinum that was the issue by the way :) !! All is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowired fields must not be static, they must be instance fields.

So change

```
@Autowired
private static MockMvc mockMvc;
```

to

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```